# Are all Windows applications working on elementary OS?

Tags: applications

I need to know If Windows Applications & Third-Part Applications are working functionally om elementary OS or not? Like MS Office 2016, Internet Download Manager, ...etc? Also, Is it functionally like MAC OS? So, It means no antivirus will be available there even as default like Windows OS?

Thank you.

Comment: i know that zorin use windows app support

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run some Windows applications using wine, you can look up compatibility here: https://appdb.winehq.org/ though you would likely have issues. There may be alternatives that you can use for example instead of Office 2016 you could use LibreOffice, OpenOffice, SoftMaker Office, or WPS Office.

In terms of antivirus there is no antivirus by default, however you could install Clam antivirus which is in the repositories for free, there are a few paid antivirus but these are generally targetting business servers. Malware is usually less of a problem for Gnu/Linux based desktops than Windows though.